# How to call a cartesian (END) coordinate system, that is referenced in surrounding air?

Tags: navigation, terminology

I'm looking for the correct/usual terminology for a coordinate system, that is moving with the wind.

I do calculations in a Cartesian East-North-Down (END) system. When taking wind into account I'd like to move this system with the wind and transform it back to an earth-fixed END-system afterwards. So basically, the reference point of my coordinate system isn't a point fixed on earth, but an air molecule that is blown with the wind.

Is there a common name for such a coordinate system?

Firstly, I thought of it as the "Wind-Frame", but after some investigations I conclude, that the term "Wind-Frame" is meaning a different system which is also rotated and not only moved in the plane.

So if any body knows, I'd like to hear from you.

I use this because I calculate Dubins paths and want to take wind into account. So when projecting the path of the plane on earth, you will see a trochoid, but the plane itself will fly a plain circle in its surrounding air. This eases calculations a great deal.

Comment: Hello again. From outside this community, there was a proposal to call my reference frame "air-frame". (not to mix up with airframe).

What's your opinion?

Obviously, such a reference frame is hardly used as I didn't find anything in the literature at all)

Answer (score 1):

Some people call it Amosphere-Fixed reference frame.
(see at: [heli-air.net](http://heli-air.net/2016/02/06/atmosphere-fixed-reference-frame-fa-axes-0axayaza/))

Just to add a thought, this name seems to imply a global reference system, whereas the velocity of air molecules may be very local.